ThingsBoard: Where to implement complex business logic
We're using ThingsBoard to manage our IoT devices, i.e. view a list of devices, see which devices are active, plot some telemetry like battery state in dashboards, perform OTA updates, etc.
Now, the devices shall no longer act independently but work together according to some business logic. There are ThingsBoard guides that explain how to use ThingsBoard's rule chains and assets to aggregate multiple device's data and manage state on a level above devices (https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rule-engine-2-0/tutorials/function-based-on-telemetry-from-two-devices/). Still, the given example is very simple and although the guide claims that much more complex scenarios could be implemented, my attempt to do so resulted in highly complicated rule chains.
Thus, we decided to implement the business logic in a server instead of low code rule chains. Now, the next challenge is to get the device data to the server and commands back to the devices. Our first idea was having the server subscribe and publish to ThingsBoard's MQTT broker to which the devices are connected. However, it seems like ThingsBoard's MQTT broker isn't meant to serve other servers than ThingsBoard itself (https://github.com/thingsboard/thingsboard/issues/318). So, what we do now is forward the devices' MQTT messages through ThingsBoard's rule chain to another MQTT broker that our server subscribes to. Then, the server controls the devices by sending RPC calls to ThingsBoard's REST interface so that ThingsBoard can send them via MQTT to the devices - according to the docs, REST is the only interface to send RPC calls from outside ThingsBoard (https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/rpc/#server-side-rpc).
That architecture seems complicated. Has someone else tried to control devices beyond Dashboard knobs and basic rule chains and could share their approach?
Here are some examples for "complex" business logic where I began to struggle with rule chains:

There are two devices assigned to one "station". When started, a device asks the server to run. The server shall allow only one device to run at a time.
If the running device doesn't send specific data for a certain time, the server shall stop it via RPC
In another scenario, there are 10 devices at a station. When an external system reports an event, the server shall start two devices that are not already running

